# New string methods substring Before/After, etc

Tags: csv, string

I'm playing with the new string toys.  I'm getting something out of a CSV (and I have very good reason to need to do that).

I tried this: contents = contents.substringAfter('/n') and it's not finding anything.  I know I have lots of '/n' in my file because contents.split('n', 2) throws up because the regex is too complicated.

Is there something I should be using instead of /n to denote a new line in a text file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A newline is most commonly denoted by the escape character \n and not /n
However, with CSV's, you may also want to check for \r\n as it will depend on the Operating System that is saving the file. [Difference between '\n' and '\r\n'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n)

```
string testString = 'Hello\nWorld';
system.debug(testString.substringAfter('\n'));

16:43:16:021 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|World
```